# The integers from 1 to 1000 are written in succession. Find the sum of all the digits.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I'm confused as to what concept I apply here. I think I need to use the sum rule but I'm not sure how to use it.

I would appreciate answers that are as detailed and easy to understand as possible, as to get my head around this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you try going from 1 to 100? see what you notice

Comment: If you had made your _question_ as detailed and easy to understand as possible, you might have explained what you mean by the "sum rule"...

Comment: You should also probably delete the irrelevant probability and statistics tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ten numbers will have every digit from 0 through 9 once as the right-most digit.
Every hundred numbers will have the second from the rightmost digit 0 through 9 ten times.
Every thousand numbers will have the third digit 0 through 9 one hundred times.
1000 adds an extra 1.

So,

$$(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)\left(100\cdot \dfrac{1000}{1000}+10\cdot \dfrac{1000}{100} + 1\cdot \dfrac{1000}{10}\right) + 1$$